# Изменение видимости кнопки CSS из скрипта JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, css-animation

```
Есть кнопка CSS (код ниже) , при нажатии на другую кнопку в событие onclick
необходимо прикрутить отображение этой кнопки, проблема в том что не могу 
скрыть её и 
в ручную , visibility: hidden и display:none не отрабатывают, что делаю не так ? 
И если можно пример обращения к видимости элемента CSS из JS :)     

          <input type="button" class = "button9" onclick="EventButton('Нажал на кнопочку 1')" value=" Кнопочка 1 ">
          <style type="text/css">
          .button9 {
          visibility: hidden;     
          }
          .button9:hover,
          .button9:active {
          background-color: #EEEEE0;
          color: black;
          font-weight: bold ;
          }
          </style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот кратенький пример, как это можно реализовать, для облегчения поиска кнопочек, в их html код я добавил атрибут id

```js
function EventButton(str) {
  console.log(str);
};

function showHideBtn1() {
  document.querySelector('#btn1').classList.toggle('invisible');
};
```

```css
.invisible {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.button9:hover,
.button9:active {
  background-color: #EEEEE0;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<p align="center">
  <input type="button" id="btn1" class="button9 invisible" onclick="EventButton('Нажал на кнопочку 1')" value=" Кнопочка 1 "></p>
<p align="center">
  <input type="button" id="btn2" class="button9" onclick="showHideBtn1()" value=" Кнопочка 2 "></p>
```

То-есть вся суть в том, что у нас есть отдельный css класс `invisible` и добавляя/удаляя его мы делаем элемент видимым/невидимым

Вот пример с доступом до css свойств, но лично мое мнение что с классом удобней

```js
function EventButton(str) {
  console.log(str);
};

function showHideBtn1() {
  var btn1 = document.getElementById('btn1');
  if(btn1.style.visibility != 'visible')
      btn1.style.visibility = 'visible';
  else
      btn1.style.visibility = 'hidden';
};
```

```css
.invisible {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.button9:hover,
.button9:active {
  background-color: #EEEEE0;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<p align="center">
  <input type="button" id="btn1" class="button9 invisible" onclick="EventButton('Нажал на кнопочку 1')" value=" Кнопочка 1 "></p>
<p align="center">
  <input type="button" id="btn2" class="button9" onclick="showHideBtn1()" value=" Кнопочка 2 "></p>
```

Comment: Спасибо, получилось :)